# Getting stock balance

Tags: mysql, join, sum

I have 3 tables as follows:

```
products:[product_id,product_name]
stock:[product_id,date,qty_received]
sales:[product_id,date,qty_sold]
```

I'm trying to display the balance of all products by subtracting qty_received - qty_sold.
My query is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.product_id, p.product_name,
IFNULL(sum(qty_received),0)-IFNULL(sum(qty_sold),0) as balance FROM products p
LEFT JOIN stock st ON (p.product_id=st.product_id)
LEFT JOIN sales sa ON (p.product_id=sa.product_id)
GROUP BY p.product_id
```

With the above query I'm not getting the correct balance.
Could you please help.

Additional Information:
Following are a simplified structure for my tables
Products table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `products` (
  `product_id` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `product_name` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `product_id` (`product_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

-- Dumping data for table `products`

```
INSERT INTO `products` (`product_id`, `product_name`) VALUES
  ('111', 'Product One'),
  ('222', 'Product Two'),
  ('333', 'Product Three'),
  ('444', 'Product Four');
```

Stock table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `stock` (
  `stock_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `product_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `qty_received` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`stock_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=112 ;
```

-- Dumping data for table `stock`

```
INSERT INTO `stock` (`stock_id`, `product_id`, `qty_received`) VALUES
  (1, 111, 5),
  (2, 222, 10),
  (3, 333, 4),
  (4, 444, 6),
  (5, 111, 2),
  (6, 222, 7),
  (7, 111, 3),
  (8, 111, 3);
```

Sales Table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sales` (
  `sales_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `product_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `qty_sold` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`sales_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=7 ;
```

-- Dumping data for table `sales`

```
INSERT INTO `sales` (`sales_id`, `product_id`, `qty_sold`) VALUES
  (1, 111, -1),
  (2, 222, -3),
  (3, 333, -2),
  (4, 111, -3),
  (5, 222, -1),
  (6, 222, -4);
```

The Result I'm getting is:

```
+------------+--------------+---------+
| product_id | product_name | balance |
+------------+--------------+---------+
| 111        | Product One  | 10      |
| 222        | Product Two  | 35      |
| 333        | Product Three| 2       |
| 444        | Product Four | 6       |
+------------+--------------+---------+
```

Correct balance I'm expecting is

```
+------------+--------------+---------+
| product_id | product_name | balance |
+------------+--------------+---------+
| 111        | Product One  | 9       |
| 222        | Product Two  | 9       |
| 333        | Product Three| 2       |
| 444        | Product Four | 6       |
+------------+--------------+---------+
```

Finally got a working sql for this solution , but not sure if this is the best way doing this.  I'm very concerned about the performance, since these tables got large amount of records.

```
SELECT p.product_id,p.product_name,
IFNULL(sum(st.qty_received),0)+IFNULL(sold,0) as balance FROM products p
  LEFT JOIN stock st ON (p.product_id=st.product_id)
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT sa.product_id,sum(sa.qty_sold) as sold FROM sales sa 
     GROUP BY sa.product_id) as t1 ON (t1.product_id=p.product_id)
GROUP BY product_id
```

Anyone can suggest a better sql (or change in schema) for better speed/performance to get stock balance?

Comment: Any chance `sales.qty_sold` is being stored as a negative number?

Comment: Yes, sales.qty_sold is stored as a negative number, hoping it would make thing easier.

Comment: You have your answer then. You need to **add** the `sum(qty_sold)` instead of **subtracting** it to get the right result. `...IFNULL(sum(qty_received),0)+IFNULL(sum(qty_sold),0) as balance...`

Comment: @asiph A sample of input, correct output and the incorrect output from your current query would help people answer. Simply telling us "it still doesn't work" leaves us shooting in the dark, so to speak.

Answer (score 2):

First, add `p.product_name` to `GROUP BY` clause.

Second, remove `DISTINCT` - it's unnecessary with `GROUP BY`.

**UPDATE**

I've tried a couple of queries and found that this one looks like the simplest:

```
SELECT 
  p.product_id, 
  p.product_name,
  COALESCE(SUM(qty), 0) as balance 
FROM products p 
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT product_id, qty_received AS qty FROM stock st UNION ALL 
    SELECT product_id, qty_sold FROM sales st
) AS T 
  ON p.product_id = T.product_id
GROUP BY 
  p.product_id, 
  p.product_name
```

Also, I think it would be a good idea to make data type of `product_id` in all your tables the same. It's `varchar` in `products` and `int` in `sales/stock`.

I did a [Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/114d5/1) for you

Comment: Its not working yet.  Noted the negative sign and it should be positive if the qty_sold is stored as negative. I also tried to display both qty_received and qty_sold in two fields, but both values are multiples of correct balance.

Comment: Yes Andrey, I have changed and no changes to the result

Comment: Can you provide some sample data, please? Do you have unique key on products table?

Comment: product_id is the unique key in products.  stock table and sales table got extra auto increment keys as a unique key.